# Mounting doorbell camera on brick facade

Tags: mounting, brick, doorbell, sealant

Unfortunately according to the mounting template, one screw hole would be in the brick and the other would be in that mess of polyurethane non-sag sealant. I'm not sure what my options are as I don't think I could properly place a mounting screw in that sealant.

[image: Mounting location for reference]

Answer (score 2):

Dig out the sealant, replace it with an appropriate mortar. You can probably shift the wire's position up or down while doing so,bto arrange things do the top hole (which takes most of the strain) will be over brick rather than mortar. Drill and fasten appropriately.

Comment: Or instead of mortar, shape a piece of PT or PVC and hammer it into the gap, then drill a mounting hole.

Answer (score 0):

Some possible options:

1. Remove sealant and put something in taht place
2. Move camera to side
3. Mount some kind of plate on wall then mount camera to plate
4. Make cavity in wall for camera
5. Use glue
6. Use epoxy resin
7. Use double sided tape

and so on